# add more items in callback function carousel google tv

Tags: google-tv

I'm using carousel.js in google tv jquery ui to create video slide. I want when I click "next" (right arrow), items will be loaded via Ajax and append to slide. This mean my app can run faster.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to load a list of thumbnails into your carousel so you don't create an empty carousel. If you really want to load video URLs using ajax each time next is clicked, you'd have to modify the following function and incorporate AJAX inside.

/**
 * Selects next Carousel item.
 * @param {boolean} true if the item should be activated after selection.
 */
gtv.jq.Carousel.prototype.selectNext = function(activate) {
  var carousel = this;

if (this.selectedItem) {
    var newItem = this.selectedItem
        .parent()
        .nextAll('.carousel-item-div')
        .eq(0)
        .find('.carousel-item');
    if (newItem && newItem.length == 0) {
      newItem = this.container.find('.carousel-item').first();
    }
    this.selectItem(this.selectedItem, newItem, function() {
      carousel.updateSelectionClasses(newItem);
      if (activate) {
        carousel.activateItem(newItem);
      }
    });
  }
};

Note that it does not make a whole lot of sense to use AJAX and load a video URL each time next button is clicked - you'd do too many ajax calls.  It's better to dynamically load video URLs for a whole category to fill a carousel using AJAX.

For example the original Google TV Templates didn't use AJAX to load video sources but this augmented Google TV Templates added AJAX loading:

https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/ajax_gtv_templates_tutorial

Check out how it's done there.

Comment: thank you very much, last night i found a jquery plugin for my problem : http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/, 
it support load ajax callback, I think it's very helpful, but I wonder how to add keycontroller to jquery plugin ?, please help me